# azure devops release pipeline keeps failing at kubectl apply?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks

In azure devops portal, my release pipeline keeps failing at kubectl apply.It says the server could not find the requested resource.

NOTE: I haven't created a kubernetes clusture in azure portal yet.so when I went to the portal to create one, it is asking for paid subscription.

logs of the release pipeline

```
2019-05-30T06:07:09.1230513Z ##[section]Starting: kubectl apply
2019-05-30T06:07:09.1348192Z ==============================================================================
2019-05-30T06:07:09.1348303Z Task         : Deploy to Kubernetes
2019-05-30T06:07:09.1348381Z Description  : Deploy, configure, update your Kubernetes cluster in Azure Container Service by running kubectl commands.
2019-05-30T06:07:09.1348441Z Version      : 0.151.2
2019-05-30T06:07:09.1348510Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-05-30T06:07:09.1348566Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851275)
2019-05-30T06:07:09.1348638Z ==============================================================================
2019-05-30T06:07:12.7827969Z [command]d:\a\_temp\kubectlTask\1559196429507\kubectl.exe --kubeconfig d:\a\_temp\kubectlTask\1559196429507\config apply -f d:\a\r1\a\_devops-sample-CI\drop\Tomcat.yaml
2019-05-30T06:07:15.1191531Z deployment "tomcat-deployment" configured
2019-05-30T06:07:15.1300152Z error: error validating "d:\\a\\r1\\a\\_devops-sample-CI\\drop\\Tomcat.yaml": error validating data: the server could not find the requested resource; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
2019-05-30T06:07:15.1454497Z ##[error]d:\a\_temp\kubectlTask\1559196429507\kubectl.exe failed with return code: 1
2019-05-30T06:07:15.1634357Z ##[section]Finishing: kubectl apply
```

Tomcat.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat-deployment
  labels:
    app: tomcat
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat
        image: suji165475/devops-sample:113
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: tomcat-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: tomcat
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

why is the server saying that it couldn't find the requested resource even though I have made sure that I created the build artifact(containing tomcat.yaml in drop folder) properly from the build ci pipeline?? Could this be due to the fact that I havent created the kubernetes clusture yet or is this due to some other reason??

also would using nodeport instead of LoadBalancer work on azure devops??

Comment: whats your k8s version? you have an extra linebreak after `---`

Comment: actually i have  installed kubernetes only on my local server.I have only pasted the content to kubeconfig while creating kubernetes connection in azure devops

Comment: do i have to create a clusture on azure devops aswell??

Comment: And i dont see any extra line breaks after ---

Comment: Have you add the Kubernetes service connection in service connection of project setting?

Comment: yes while creating the release pipeline i created a kubernetes service connection and pasted the kubeconfig content of my local clusture

Comment: can i connect my local clusture to azure devops this way or do i have to create a seperate clusture in azure

Comment: No, microsoft not limit the cluster target in Azure, we also provide the connection to the local client. So you don't must create cluster in Azure. By the way, what's the version of kubectl do you download while you execute apply task in release? I found when I use one outdated kubectl, I can have your same error.

Comment: in the page where i create new release pipeline under advanced option kubectl version spec is 1.7.0

Comment: also the version option was seleted by default instead of specify location

Comment: since iam using local kubernetes clusture do i have to select the specify location option instead of version option and select the kubectl.exe from local server??

Comment: Yes, of course you can. But if you still use with Version, please try with 1.14.3 in your Kubectl tool installer task. And in Advanced, specified with 1.14.3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain if you are using local kubernetes cluster and given this error - the issue is with the fact that Azure Devops cant reach you kubernetes cluster. You should make sure your cluster is exposed on a certain IP and ports are not blocked.

Comment: i have tried this on my local server and deployed it to the local clusture and it works

Comment: problem is only when i try to deploy on azure devops

Comment: how can i connect azure devops to the local clusture without having to create a new clusture in azure devops??